# Tomcat default page

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am supporting a 3rd party app using IIS & tomcat. I got the app installed and running fine at myserver:8080/mydir

but the problem is if you just go to myserver:8080 you see a default Tomcat administration page. I am concerned that this might pose a security risk and would like to either turn off, block, or redirect this page.

the constraint is that I can't change the way the site is configured per se (like changing the name to ROOT or whatever) or I will mess up my vendor support.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a redirect in the ...ROOT/index.html file, for example:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.google.com">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Undeploy the ROOT context and you'll get a 400 response. FWIW, I don't believe there are any currently-known vulnerabilities in Tomcat's ROOT webapp, but it's a good practice to undeploy it because it's really not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to set this page visible only for administrators. Somewhere in conf/tomcat-users.xml you could add admins like:
    user username="admin" password="your_pwd" roles="manager"

Comment: There's no need to set permissions: you can simply undeploy the ROOT context.